# Python reads \n as string

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I am using python `2.7.9`, and OS X Yosemite. I have a file called `list.dat`, which contains the following:

```
item1, a
item2, b
item3, c
```

and I have a python script:

```
list=[]
f=open('list.dat','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    list.append(line.rsplit(','))

f.close()

print list
```

Which produces the output:

```
[['item1', ' a\n'], ['item2', ' b\n'], ['item3', ' c']]
```

Are the `\n`s supposed to appear in the output? If so, how can I modify the code so that they don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'\n'` signifies a new line, which evidently is there in your text file. Thus, the `'\n'`s are supposed to appear in the output.

Essentially, your `.dat` file is:

```
item1, a\n
item2, b\n
item3, c\n
```

To remove that, try the following:

```
list=[]
f=open('list.dat','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    list.append(line.strip('\n').rsplit(','))

f.close()

print list
```

This uses `str.strip('\n')` to remove the new-lines (`'\n'`s) from the string.

---

```
>>> list=[]
>>> f=open('list.dat','r')
>>> for line in f.readlines():
...     list.append(line.strip('\n').rsplit(','))
... 
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> print list
[['item1', ' a'], ['item2', ' b'], ['item3', ' c']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `replace` or `strip` function.

And never name your list as `"list"` because [list is a python builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

```
list1=[]
f=open('list.dat','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    list1.append(line.rsplit(',').strip('\n'))

f.close()

print list1
```

Comment: `str.strip('\n')` is designed for this task, `str.replace` has obvious flaws and is thus less pythonic in this situation

Answer (score 1):

'\n' is the newline-character. You have to remove it manually or use the `csv`-module:

```
import csv
with open('list.dat') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
print data
```

Comment: this solution is more `pythonic`: it uses a context manager to handle file open/closing & the built in csv module leads to shorter code that is easier to read and write.